# When I try to review First Posts, why does it say "No Action Needed"?

Tags: support, review

Whenever I try to review a 1st post, it says no action required. Is it possible to have it show only posts that I can review?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> button means that the post is good *in your opinion*. However, it doesn't mean you have to press it.

A post may need improvement, it may need to be flagged, it may need you to ask the OP for more clarification, etc.

Knowing that, if you try to do any of the previous actions (suggest an edit, flag, comment, etc.), the <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> button will be disabled, and the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button will be enabled instead.

If you click on `(more)`, you can see more details about what to do in a review.

[image: Firt post review]